# Any graph api call to create Azure b2c tenant

Tags: azure-rest-api, azure-rbac, azure-service-principal, azure-ad-b2c

We want to create Azure b2c tenant using Graph api.

We tried searching in Internet and got how to create b2c tenant from portal. This is the reference we found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant

But we want to get the same results using graph calls. We have one service principal having owner role and global administrator roles.

Is there any existing graph api call that helps us to create tenant?

If not, any REST api call also okay for us. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create B2C tenants with a service principal, You must use an ARM API, not Graph API.

You can use ARM API create B2C tenant, reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/activedirectory/b2c-tenants/create?tabs=HTTP#scopes